# JS скрипт ведет себя по разному во время дебага и во время обычной работы

Tags: javascript, json, циклы, xlsx

У меня задача, на стороне клиента взять записи из xlsx файла, преобразовать их в json нужного вида и отправить на сервер.
Для этого использую библиотеку xlsx-js. Получаю нужны объект и в цикле прохожусь по всем доступным строкам и столбцам.
При работе с таблицей с 3-10 строками скрипт работает корректно и правильно создает json.
Когда же я открываю таблицу где 1000+ строк, в консоли отображается ошибка `TypeError: book.Sheets[SheetName][cord] is undefined` это undefined (в функциях readGeo, readProduct, readName,readPhone, readPhone).
При этом когда я ставлю точку остановки и по шагово смотрю что происходит - алгоритм работает так как нужно.

```
function readGeo(book,row) {
    const cord = COLUMNGEO+row;
    let ret = book.Sheets[SheetName][cord].v;
    return ret;
}

function readProduct(book, row) {
    const cord = COLUMNPRODUCT+row;
    return book.Sheets[SheetName][cord].v;
}

function readName(book, row) {
    const cord = COLUMNNAME+row;
    return book.Sheets[SheetName][cord].v;
}

function readPhone(book, row) {
    const cord =COLUMNPHONE+row;
    return book.Sheets[SheetName][cord].v;
}

function readrow(book, row) {
    let lead = { 'geo' : readGeo(book,row),
                     'product' : readProduct(book,row),
                     'name' : readName(book, row),
                     'phone' : readPhone(book,row)
                    };
    return lead;
}

function getCountLeads(book) {
    let ref = book.Sheets[SheetName]["!ref"];
    let pattern = RegulerPatternForTable; 
    return ref.matchAll(pattern).next().value[1];
}

function ConvertToJson(book) { //извлекает в удобной структуре данные из книги
    let count = Number( getCountLeads(book) ); //определяем количество заполненных строк
    let result = {"leads" : []};
    for(let i=1;i<=count;i++) {
        result.leads.push(readrow(book, i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Объясните почему так происходит, и как заставить работать нормально?

Comment: ДА небось у тебя где-то что-то ajax'ом подгружается. И во время дебага оно успевает догрузиться, а во время простой работы - нет

Comment: поставил в функцию ConvertToJson проверку book на undefine, все в норме. остальные функции такие как в вопросе, нигде ajax не использую. 
Если сделал остановку при дебаге( по идее должно подгрузить и нормально заработать если есть ajax), но при снятии точки остановки и продолжении работы скрипта все равно ошибка появляется.

Comment: Значит ошибка где то в данных, и происходит когда до невалидных данных доходите, поставте в инструментах разработчика - бряк при ошибке("приостанавливать при ошибке" на вкладке "источники") и будет видно

Comment: Или оберните это в try catch и обложитесь в блоке catch консоль.логами на всю цепочку book.Sheets[SheetName][cord].v.  book, book.Sheets, SheetName, book.Sheets[SheetName] и т.д. увидите, что не пришло

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в выходе за пределы массива.
Функция `getCountLeads(book)` берет количество строк по регулярному выражению `const RegulerPatternForTable = /^A1:D(\d+)$/gm;` на маленьких таблицах работало нормально но на таблице с 1000 строками результат получается 1221.